# Single Logout with CAS

Tags: ssl, spring-security, ssl-certificate, cas, jasig

I have an environment with a cas server and any java clients. I'm facing a problem with single logout with all clients, because, the client do a redirect to path /cas/logout and only this session is logged out. The ticket inside the cookie CASTG is cleaned up, but the user yet can access other applications, but, when the client try access the application that user did redirect to /cas/logout, the cas server asks user credentials.

According I saw when you do a request to a /cas/logout this works like a chain, where CAS server do sign out one by one.

Obviously is a configuration problem, but, I'm not able to find it.

Important: When a user do a request to cas/logout two cookies are deleted, CASTGC and CASPRIVACY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the CAS server should send logout requests to all applications the user has accessed when you call /cas/logout, in addition to the deletion of its own cookies (CASTGC and CASPRIVACY). The property managing that is: https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/master/cas-server-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/cas.properties#L75...

Comment: I did set up this line too. Analyzing the log I see that the CAS Server try to send a request to applications accessed by the user but, prints a SSLHandshakeException. My applications works with secure connection as well as CAS Server. I should put in cacerts of JVM that runs CAS all certificates of my applications ?

Comment: Yes, the CAS server must be able to communicate with the application directly and thus, have the appropriate certificate in its truststore / keystore.

Comment: I have one Apache and underneath multiple applications running on JBOSS. In other words I have the same certificate to CAS and to applications. If the SSO works, SLogout too should work, right, because is the same certificate. Or all jboss instances should have a certificate ?

Comment: I'm not a certificate specialist, but I imagine that you have installed your own SSL certificate to enable SSL on CAS server and applications side. To communicate with them (the CAS server is a client for the applications), you need to add the certificate authorities to trust your server certificate...